# В квадрат вписана окружность. Определите площадь заштрихованной части фигуры, если известна стороны квадрата

Tags: c#, visual-studio, консоль

Что нужно добавить чтобы получить ответ?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double n = 0;
            string s = "";
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите число > 0");
                s = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (double.TryParse(s, out n) == false || n <= 0);


            double pl = Math.Sqrt(n)-((Math.Sqrt(n)-Math.PI*Math.Sqrt(n/2))/2);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возвращайте 0. Ничего ведь не заштриховано

Comment: А мне говорили, что дети старше 4 лет уже в курсе того, что не все знают то, что знает он)

Comment: а что у вас заштриховано окружность или "внешняя часть"?

Comment: Sqrt - это взятие квадратного корня, а не возведение в квадрат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить вывод.

```
 Console.WriteLine(pl);
```